# Простое серверное приложение

Tags: java, парсер, сервер

Есть бесплатный хостинг с доменом третьего уровня. На хостинге есть Apache/2.4.1, я могу беспрепятственно копировать туда файлы.

Я хочу прояснить несколько моментов. Мне нужно сделать на сервере парсер, который раз в час будет разбирать RSSки нескольких сайтов.

Мне не ясно следующее:
Какой язык для этого лучше использовать? Как обеспечить переодичность? Как развернуть этот парсер на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишите на том языке, который лучше знаете. Мне лично бы подошел perl/python, возможно даже php. Хотя может быть даже обычным curl/wget + bash.

Периодичность наиболее просто обеспечить обычным cron'ом. Но есть ли доступ к нему - я не знаю. В этом случае можно написать свой скрипт, который просто будет запускаться, выполнять свои действия и потом немного ждать (с помощью sleep).

Развернуть на сервере - скопируйте файлы с скриптами и настройте крон.